# Computing the Electric Field of a Weirdly Shaped Wire

Tags: electrostatics

The typical examples presented when computing electric (vector) fields are uniformly charged straight wires and semicircles, and they actually do not compute the entire vector field, but simply the vector at a single point. My question is how do I approach computing the electric field for weirder objects that perhaps do not have uniform charge, and give a formula represent the vector at any point (so that I can actually plot the vector field and field lines)?

For example, suppose that we have a wire given by $\mathbf{x}(t) = (x_1(t),x_2(t)) = (t, t + t\cdot \sin(t))$ on $[-4\pi,4\pi]$:

$\hskip2in$ [image]

and the charge at any point on the wire can be found by $f(\mathbf{x}(t)) = x_1(t)^2 - x_2(t)$. How do I compute the electric field $E(\mathbf{r})$? Here, I want the actual vector field so that the outputs are also vectors: $\mathbf{r} \to E(\mathbf{r})$.

I get that such example with this $f$ does not have physical significance, but there has to be a general formula to compute such a thing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can divide the wire into very small pieces, where you know the charge of each particular piece. Then you sum up all the electric fields of each of these pieces.

Say we cut the wire into pieces of equal length along the $x$ axis, and let's call this value $dx$. I will use $y(x)=x+x\sin x$. We can calculate the length of the piece of wire at some $x$ value using $$dl=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}$$
We have $y'=1+\sin x+x\cos x$
The charge of this piece is $dq=f(x)dl(x)$.

If we want to calculate the electric field at $(x_0,y_0)$, we can write the position of this point with respect to $(x,y)$ on the wire as $\vec r=(x_0-x,y_0-y)$. The electric field of $dq$ is going to be $$d\vec{E}=\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}dq\frac{\vec r}{r^3}$$
We can now write the $x$ and $y$ components. Just focus on $x$ ($y$ is similar):
$$dE_x=\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}dq\frac{x_0-x}{r^3}$$
The final step is to integrate $x$ from $-4\pi$ to $4\pi$. It will not be nice for this problem, but you might be able to do it numerically.

Comment: Thank you! This is pretty much what I figured. It is simply changing the distribution to one who's "weight" is $f(x)$. If I have time, I may implement a program that will compute such things numerically. That sounds like a fun task!